# Generic Maps with Map<KeyType, ValueType> in Java

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I have a class, `TestMap`, with only static methods (including a `main`) which is used to test `Maps`.  There is a method in the class, as an example, which accepts a map and the types of the key and value are denoted as `KeyType` and `ValueType` respectively, as shown below;

```
public static <KeyType,ValueType> void printMap( String msg, Map<KeyType,ValueType> m )
{
    System.out.println( msg + ":" );
    Set<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>> entries = m.entrySet( );

    for( Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType> thisPair : entries )
    {
        System.out.print( thisPair.getKey( ) + ": " );
        System.out.println( thisPair.getValue( ) );
    }
}
```

My question is, if I want to re-write this class so that it can be instantiated, and not comprised of only static methods, how can I define a map within the class that could work with the `Map<KeyType, ValueType>`?

I tried to define a map as below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private Map<KeyType, ValueType> internalMap;
```

Any ideas?

Per the first comment, I tried to add  to the class defnition, and then I setup a constructor as follows;

```
public class TestMap<KeyType, ValueType>
{
    private Map<KeyType, ValueType> internalMap;

    /*
     * Constructor which accepts a generic Map for testing
    */
    public <KeyType,ValueType> TestMap(Map<KeyType, ValueType> m)
    {
       this.internalMap = m;
    }       
}
```

However, the assignment in the constructor is throwing an error saying it is a Type Mismatch, and that it can't convert from java.util.Map to java.util.Map

Comment: Don't repeat the type parameters on the constructor itself. See my answer.

Comment: You don't need type parameters on the constructor.

Comment: @Chris Corbin: Please don't edit your question to be a new problem after the question is already marked as answered.  You won't attract new answers (because the question looks like it's already answered) and it isn't fair to people who have already answered (because their answers no longer apply to your new question).  Instead, just ask a new question by clicking the "Ask Question" button in the upper-right corner of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `internalMap` as you have tried, but since `Map` is an interface, you need to instantiate it with a concrete class type (e.g., `HashMap`, `TreeMap`, etc.)

```
public class TestMap<KeyType, ValueType> {
    private Map<KeyType, ValueType> internalMap;

    public TestMap() {
        internalMap = new HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>();
    }

    public TestMap(Map<KeyType, ValueType> m) {
        internalMap = m;
    }

    public void printMap( String msg )
    {
        System.out.println( msg + ":" );
        Set<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>> entries = internalMap.entrySet( );

        for( Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType> thisPair : entries )
        {
            System.out.print( thisPair.getKey( ) + ": " );
            System.out.println( thisPair.getValue( ) );
        }
    }

    . . . // methods to add to internal map, etc.
}
```

Comment: What if I want the constructor to accept a Map<KeyType, ValueType>, and then assign this to internalMap?

Comment: @ChrisCorbin - Edited to show how it's done. Just eliminate the type parameters on the constructor declaration.

Comment: Thanks!  My textbook had the following for the constructor; public <KeyType, ValueType> TestMap(Map<KeyType, ValueType m) { ... }  When I removed the extra <KeyType, ValueType> afetr public it works.

Comment: Yeesh. What textbook is this? It ought to have a hazard label on it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this:

```
class MyMap<KeyType, ValueType> {
    private Map<KeyType, ValueType> internalMap;
}
```

**Edit**: You don't need type parameters on the constructor:

```
class TestMap<KeyType, ValueType>
{
    private Map<KeyType, ValueType> internalMap;

    /*
     * Constructor which accepts a generic Map for testing
    */
    public TestMap(Map<KeyType, ValueType> m)
    {
       this.internalMap = m;
    }       
}
```

Comment: @Ted Hopp: He only said he tried the internal map definition and it "didn't work". I assume he missed the type parameters on the class itself.

Comment: Okay, good inference. I assumed the problem was instantiating a generic map, but you're probably right (especially given OP's edit).